# Timer since a user is logged on in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, authentication, timer

The problem is as follows: I have the time (in hh:mm:ss) when a user logs into the app. Now I have to implement a clock from that "log-in" time to the current time. This should be updated every second in the display. As an example: Say, the user logs in at 09:00:00 and the current time is 10:00:00. Then , the display should say 01:00:00 -> 01:00:01 -> 01:00:02 -> ...... So, the display is updated every second.

I am new to Xcode and objective C. Could you please suggest some approach? Thank You

Comment: I don't think Xcode can tell you the time. Did you mean to do this in your *iOS app?*

Comment: this has nothing to do with xcode - Xcode is just a tool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start and stop timer in app delegate methods like

application:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions, 
application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions,
applicationDidBecomeActive:
applicationWillResignActive:
applicationDidEnterBackground:
applicationWillEnterForeground:
applicationWillTerminate:

Refer to the following document for more info:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html